# Calculator and a floating point modulus function in C

Tags: c

I have to write a case for a '%' (modulus) function for a calculator.
When I compile, it tells me I have used the `fmod` function incorrectly.
Without the case '%', the rest of the code works as it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>    // Originally missing

#define MAXOP 100
#define NUMBER '0'

int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);

main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    printf("\nEnter numbers below in the following format\nwith a space between each:\n");
    printf("\tnum1 num2 operator\n");
    printf("\tyou may use (+, -, /, *) for the operators\n");

    while((type = getop(s)) != EOF)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case NUMBER:
                push(atof(s));
                break;

            case '+':
                push(pop() + pop());
                break;

            case '*':
                push(pop() * pop());
                break;

            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                push(pop() - op2);
                break;

            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                if(op2 != 0.0)
                    push(pop() / op2);
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor\n");
                break;

              case '%':
                op2=pop();
                if(op2 != 0.0)
                    push(fmod(pop(),op2));
                else
                    printf("error: zero divisor");
                break;

            case '\n':
                printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
                break;
            default:
                printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I looked up the `fmod` function, and I still can not figure out why it will not work.  Any thoughts?

I added the math.h header, and the error message I am getting now is:

```
/tmp/ccgiVhWI.o: In function `main':
calc.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `fmod'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Why not use the modulus operator (%)?

Comment: @KevinMangold: because both operands of `%` must be integers, but he is dealing with floating point numbers.

Comment: Note that the 'percentage function' is not a particularly accurate description.  It is a modulus function.

Comment: As @ooga noted, you need to link with the maths library, which is often (usually) referenced by `-lm` on the compiler command line (and refers to a file `libm.so` or `libm.a` in a system library directory).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `#include <math.h>` so the compiler thinks `fmod()` is a function returning `int`, or it is complaining that it knows about `fmod()` but you've not declared it properly, or thereabouts.

You would do better to include the exact compiler error message (unless there's a very long path for the file name, in which case truncating the file name would be a courtesy).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `math.h` header to provide the prototype for `fmod`.

Comment: I added the math.h header and am now getting:                calc.c:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `fmod' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @minenerd Try adding `-lm` to the command line to explicitly link with the math library.