# C Programing Assignment - Math Tutor - Division and remainder logic - Can I do this a better way?

Tags: c

So I wrote this program for a Programing in C Assignment. It useds a switch menu entry to pick between Randomly generated problems from Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division.

The only problem I had when I made it was the division section. How do you deal with randomly generated numbers that don't evenly divide into. So I thought, "Ok don't even deal with decimal points with them as floats and just go straight integers. then use mod of the two randomly generated digits to have the use enter in the remainder if there is any."

So this is what I cam up with.

```
void division(){

int a,b;
int ans, uans;
int remain, uremain;

a=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
b=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;

printf("What is\n");
printf("   %.0f\n",a);
printf(" ÷ %.0f\n",b);
printf("========\n");
printf("?= ");

scanf("%d",&uans);

printf("\n Remainder = ");

scanf("%d",&uremain);

ans = a / b;
remain = a % b;


if(ans==uans && remain==uremain){
    printf("\n\nCorrect!.......\n\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d with a remainder of %.0f\n",ans, remain);
}
else{
    printf("\n\nIncorrect!......\n\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d with a remainder of %d\n",ans, remain);
}
}
```

Is there any better way to do this to account for maybe not having to enter in remainder if there isn't a remainder I'm assuming i could do something like if( remain > 0) to see if there is a remainder and then add it but just wondering what others think.

For context here is the full program

```
/*****************************

CS 50 - Programing in C
Math tutor

Write a program that displays a menu as shown in the sample run. 
You can enter 1, 2, 3, or 4 for choosing an addition, subtraction, multiplication, 
or division test. After a test is finished, the menu is redisplayed. 
You may choose another test or enter 5 to exit the system. 

Each test generates two random single-digit numbers to form a question for addition,
subtraction, multiplication, or division. 

For a subtraction such as number1 – number2,

number1 is greater than or equal to number2.  

For a division question such as number1 / number2, number2 is not zero.

******************************/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

int displaymenu();
void addition();
void subtraction();
void multiplication();
void division();


int main(){

int com;
srand(time(NULL));

do{
    com = displaymenu();
    switch(com){
        case 1:
            addition();
            break;
        case 2:
            subtraction();
            break;
        case 3:
            multiplication();
            break;
        case 4:
            division();
            break;
        case 5: printf("Have a nice day\n");
    }
}while(com != 5);   

//needed for all basic programs to run for the professor
system("pause");

return(0);
}

int displaymenu(){

int choice;

printf("*-----------------------*\n");
printf("|       MATH TUTOR      |\n");
printf("*-----------------------*\n");
printf("*    1. Addition        *\n");
printf("*    2. Subtration      *\n");
printf("*    3. Multiplication  *\n");
printf("*    4. Division        *\n");
printf("*    5. EXIT            *\n");
printf("*-----------------------*\n");
printf("Menu Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&choice);
return choice;      
}

void addition(){

int a,b, ans;

a=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
b=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;

printf("What is\n");
printf("   %d\n",a);
printf(" + %d\n",b);
printf("========\n");
printf("?= ");
scanf("%d",&ans);

if((a+b)==ans){
    printf("\n\nCorrect!.......\n\n");
}
else{
    printf("\n\nIncorrect!......\n\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d\n",a+b);
}   
}

void subtraction(){

int a,b, ans;

a=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
b=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;

printf("What is\n");
printf("   %d\n",a);
printf(" - %d\n",b);
printf("========\n");
printf("?= ");
scanf("%d",&ans);

if((a-b)==ans){
    printf("\n\nCorrect!.......\n\n");
}
else{
    printf("\n\nIncorrect!......\n\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d\n",a-b);
}   
}

void multiplication(){

int a,b, ans;

a=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
b=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;

printf("What is\n");
printf("   %d\n",a);
printf(" x %d\n",b);
printf("========\n");
printf("?= ");
scanf("%d",&ans);

if((a*b)==ans){
    printf("\n\nCorrect!.......\n\n");
}
else{
    printf("\n\nIncorrect!......\n\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d\n",a*b);
}   
}

void division(){

int a,b;
int ans, uans;
int remain, uremain;

a=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
b=rand()%(100-1+1)+1;

ans = a / b;
remain = a % b;

printf("What is\n");
printf("   %d\n",a);
printf(" ÷ %d\n",b);
printf("========\n");
printf("?= ");
scanf("%d",&uans);


if(remain > 0){
    printf("\nRemainder = ");
    scanf("%d",&uremain);
}



if(ans==uans && remain==uremain){
    printf("\n\nCorrect!.......\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d with a remainder of %d\n",ans, remain);
}
else{
    printf("\n\nIncorrect!......\n");
    printf("\n\nThe answer was %d with a remainder of %d\n\n\n\n",ans, remain);
}   
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want your user to have to enter a remainder?  Even if the remainder is 0, it's possible for the user to enter a remainder greater than 0 and have a wrong answer

Comment: Maybe [Calculator and a floating point module function in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491336/calculator-and-a-floating-point-modulus-function-in-c) will help?

Comment: I'm trying to make it a simple app and not making anything super fancy. I understand there is already a function for a lot of stuff but I just want to do a basic app again. I think I need to add a bit about if the int b is 0 redo the random number just incase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate your division problems the same way you do multiplication ones, but use the product and one of the numbers for the problem, the other number being the solution.

That is, generate `a` and `b` as you do in `multiplication`, then ask what is `a*b` divided by `a` (so that `b` is the answer).

Comment: Can you should me what you mean by context? I posted the whole program to get a better Idea of what i did.

Comment: I did it this way `do{
  a = rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
  b = rand()%(100-1+1)+1;
  ans = a * b;
  remain = a % b;
 }while(a < b || b == 0 || remain > 0);`

Comment: Sure, though that can take an arbitrarily large amount of time (since you have no idea how many iterations it will take), and it gives the wrong answer.

Comment: It claims the answer to `a` divided by `b` is `a*b`.